# Bash - search and loop over multiple string matches

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I have a somewhat complex shell script that I am attempting to write.  I will give an example to describe it. I have a file with the following text:

```
othertextbefore
WORDSFRONT
stuffBEGINstuff
stuffMIDstuff
stuffENDstuff
WORDSBACK
WORDSFRONT
stuffDIFFBEGINstuff
stuffDIFFMIDstuff
stuffDIFFENDstuff
WORDSBACK
(repeating)
othertestafter
```

What I need to do is search the file and identify each block that is wrapped in WORDSFRONT and WORDSBACK.  I then need to take the contents in that found block and do some parsing/building of the text within it (basically extract BEGIN etc. and rebuild a new text file with them).

I am having trouble with the first part mostly, I just need to know how to identify each block of text and then loop over each block.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
/WORDSBACK/ {z=0}
z
/WORDSFRONT/ {z=1}
```

Output

```
stuffBEGINstuff
stuffMIDstuff
stuffENDstuff
stuffDIFFBEGINstuff
stuffDIFFMIDstuff
stuffDIFFENDstuff
```

Answer (score 1):

> I just need to know how to identify each block of text and then loop over each block.

#### Using awk

From what you have described so far, awk is the natural tool for this.  The following illustrates how to identify blocks and process each line from the block, in this case printing out the BEGIN lines:

```
$ awk '/WORDSFRONT/{f=1} f && /BEGIN/{print "Found new block with begin=",$0;} /wordsback/{f=0}' file
Found new block with begin= stuffBEGINstuff
Found new block with begin= stuffDIFFBEGINstuff
```

In the above, the flag `f` is used to determine whether we are in a block.

#### Using shell

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    [[ $line =~ WORDSFRONT ]] && f=1
    [[ $f == 1 && $line =~ BEGIN ]] && echo "Found new block with begin=$line"
    [[ $line =~ WORDSBACK ]] && f=0
done <file
```

When run, the above produces the output:

```
Found new block with begin=stuffBEGINstuff
Found new block with begin=stuffDIFFBEGINstuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl range operator

```
while (<>)
{
  if ( my $num =  /WORDSFRONT/ .. /WORDSBACK/ ) {
    print "$num\t$.\t$_";
  }
}

$num is the line number within the block. It is 1 when a new block begins. 
When the block ends, "E0" is appended to this.
if ($num == 2), we are at the 2nd line of the current block.
if ($num =~ /E/), we are at the end of the current block.

$. is the line number within the file.
$_ is the actual line
```

With the given sample file, it produces the following output

```
1       2       WORDSFRONT
2       3       stuffBEGINstuff
3       4       stuffMIDstuff
4       5       stuffENDstuff
5E0     6       WORDSBACK
1       7       WORDSFRONT
2       8       stuffDIFFBEGINstuff
3       9       stuffDIFFMIDstuff
4       10      stuffDIFFENDstuff
5E0     11      WORDSBACK
```